# XNA: unknown loading music error appeared

Tags: c#, monogame

I'm currently going through a book which teaches XNA. I have followed all the instructions to add background music but for some reason I keep getting this error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.ContentLoadException' occurred in MonoGame.Framework.dll
>
> Additional information: Could not load Gobbledigook asset!

I have access to the media library and this is my line of code

```
MediaPlayer.Play(Content.Load<Song>("Gobbledigook"));
```

The song "Gobbledigook" is in my Content map and these are the properties

[image]

Does someone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because XNA (and MonoGame) *Content Manager* cannot load your audio file in its MP3 format. It will have to go through *Content Build Pipeline* first. MonoGame has its own pipeline ready for the job.

Firstly, open up *Content.mgcb* located in your *Content* folder (using *Solution Explorer*). Tool called *MonoGame Pipeline* should be opened now which you can use to import your assets.

[image]

If you build your project now, you can notice the WMA and XNB files in bin directory.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, perfect! Thank you very much :)